# Power series of $\sqrt{1-x}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

A question says:
True / False

There exists a power series about $a = 0$ with infinite convergence ratio, that converges to the function

$f(x) = \sqrt{1-x}$

I know the function is differentiable infinity times at $a=0$, but how can you find the convergence ratio or how can you know it's not infinity?

Comment: Find the power series. Maybe something can be seen from the coefficients? You never know until you've tried.

Comment: What do you know about analytic functions?

Comment: I found the first 4 coefficients, all I can see it's that they are negative and descending, Still, I cannot conclude how it helps me. About the analytic functions, I don't think we ever talked about that. The last material we have learned is Taylor series. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you consider $f$ as a function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$? In that case, the answer is quite obvious. Consider the definition of the convergence ratio and what happens with $f(x)$ for $x>1$.

Comment: So, the power series will be always negative, as sqrt(1-x) , x>1  will be always non-negative, therefore the claim is false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power series with a positive convergence radius give holomorphic functions. If a power series (centered at the origin) converges to $\sqrt{1-x}$ over a neighbourhood of the origin, it has to be the Maclaurin series of $\sqrt{1-x}$, namely
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{4^n(1-2n)}x^n $$
by the principle of analytic continuation. On the other hand the radius of convergence of such power series is one, either from the fact that 
$$\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n} = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(\cos\theta\right)^{2n}\,d\theta \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}, $$
or from the fact that the previous series is a $\phantom{}_2 F_1\left(\ldots,x\right)$, or from the fact that $\sqrt{1-z}$ has a singularity (a branch point) at $z=1$. In particular no entire function equals $\sqrt{1-x}$ over a neighbourhood of the origin.